# Streamline this script

Tags: javascript, jquery, reveal.js

I have some code that works but I just need to know whether I can reduce this down/streamline the script a bit better. The script works in conjuction with JQUERY's reveal script and stops Vimeo video playing when the reveal window is closed. I got the original script from StckOverlow but this was based on one video - I have 11.

My script is as follows and as you'll see there seems to be alot of repetition. Is there any way to streamline this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
           $('body').live('click',function(){
            if($('div.reveal-modal-bg').is(':visible')){
                var resourceVideo = $('#myModal-1 iframe').attr('src');
                $('#myModal-1 iframe').attr('src','').attr('src',resourceVideo);
                };
            if($('div.reveal-modal-bg').is(':visible')){
                var resourceVideo = $('#myModal-2 iframe').attr('src');
                $('#myModal-2 iframe').attr('src','').attr('src',resourceVideo);
                };
            if($('div.reveal-modal-bg').is(':visible')){
                var resourceVideo = $('#myModal-3 iframe').attr('src');
                $('#myModal-3 iframe').attr('src','').attr('src',resourceVideo);
                };
            if($('div.reveal-modal-bg').is(':visible')){
                var resourceVideo = $('#myModal-4 iframe').attr('src');
                $('#myModal-4 iframe').attr('src','').attr('src',resourceVideo);
                };
            if($('div.reveal-modal-bg').is(':visible')){
                var resourceVideo = $('#myModal-5 iframe').attr('src');
                $('#myModal-5 iframe').attr('src','').attr('src',resourceVideo);
                };
            if($('div.reveal-modal-bg').is(':visible')){
                var resourceVideo = $('#myModal-6 iframe').attr('src');
                $('#myModal-6 iframe').attr('src','').attr('src',resourceVideo);
                };
            if($('div.reveal-modal-bg').is(':visible')){
                var resourceVideo = $('#myModal-7 iframe').attr('src');
                $('#myModal-7 iframe').attr('src','').attr('src',resourceVideo);
                };
            if($('div.reveal-modal-bg').is(':visible')){
                var resourceVideo = $('#myModal-8 iframe').attr('src');
                $('#myModal-8 iframe').attr('src','').attr('src',resourceVideo);
                };
            if($('div.reveal-modal-bg').is(':visible')){
                var resourceVideo = $('#myModal-9 iframe').attr('src');
                $('#myModal-9 iframe').attr('src','').attr('src',resourceVideo);
                };
            if($('div.reveal-modal-bg').is(':visible')){
                var resourceVideo = $('#myModal-10 iframe').attr('src');
                $('#myModal-10 iframe').attr('src','').attr('src',resourceVideo);
                };
            if($('div.reveal-modal-bg').is(':visible')){
                var resourceVideo = $('#myModal-11 iframe').attr('src');
                $('#myModal-11 iframe').attr('src','').attr('src',resourceVideo);
                };                                      
            })
        });
        </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: you're just resetting the `src` to exactly what it was? And all the `if` conditions are exactly the same - you just need 1 with everything else inside it

Comment: I don't get it, if the condition is true, every statement will execute and you will just end up with the last condition being set

Comment: Yeh, from first glance, you can wrap all those statements in one if block!

Comment: @StephenSmith the script seems broken as it currently is.. looks like it will set the `src` of all 11 `iframes` at the same time. Is that what you want ? If you could post your HTML and describe what you want to happen and when, we could help more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('body').live('click',function(){
            if($('div.reveal-modal-bg').is(':visible')){
                $('div[id*=myModal] iframe').each(function() {
                    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
                });
            };                                      
        })
    });
</script>
```

The `$('div[id*=myModal] iframe')` selects all divs with an ID that contains "myModal", please note that you would need to change this if you are using a different HTML tag.

Despite this, I am not sure of the purpose of your code, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Ian, I've added this script in and it has worked!!!! Thank you very much for your help. Its nice to have someone just help rather than make stupid sarcastic comments as above. Much appreciated.

Comment: No worries, if you could vote up and accept the answer that would be great. I think you only got the negative comments as to someone who has been coding for a while the duplication seemed obvious. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks Ian. Accepted the answer but can't vote up yet. My reputation isn't high enough. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to do something like this:

```
if($('div.reveal-modal-bg').is(':visible')){
    $('iframe').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
    });
};
```

Why are you trying to set the `src` attribute to exactly the same value?